# comparing of mix,max values of two sub types in Ada using ASIS

Tags: ada, asis

I want to compare min, max of values of two subtypes. In Ada language it is possible to assign between two different subtypes, for example

```ada
procedure Example_1 is
   subtype Type_1 is Integer range 0 .. 10;
   subtype Type_2 is Integer range 0 .. 30;
   A : Type_1 := 0;
   B : Type_2 := 12;
begin
   A := B;
end Example_1;
```

At run time `A := B` can give range overflow error. In ASIS, is it possible to compare subtypes, min/max values of subtypes (integer, real, enumeration types) so that I can identify overflow problem before run-time?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler detects this problem when compiled with -gnatVa -gnat12

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to check this with ASIS.

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582918/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-expressions-for-a-string-field-in-a-reco) for how to extract `'First` and `'Last` for a subtype.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I getting exception in "sub_constraint" call for enumeration type. Please let me know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: I can't help you with that without a bit more context.  Maybe you should compose a new question, demonstrating how far you've got. - Or just update this one with additional context.